# Its saying I have no row selected?

Tags: sql, oracle

It's saying I have no row selected.

This is the question:
Find the member ID, last name, and first name of the members who have never borrowed any books in the past or currently.

This is the schema, Primary Keys are bold.

Book(**bookID**, ISBN, title, author, publish-year, category)

Member(**memberID**, lastname, firstname, address, phone-number, limit)

CurrentLoan(**memberID**, **bookID**, loan-date, due-date)

History(**memberID**, **bookID**, loan-date, return-date)

Members can borrow books from the library.  The number of books they can borrow is limited by the “limit” field of the Member relation (it may differ for different members). The category of a book includes fiction, non-fiction, children’s and reference.  The CurrentLoan table represents the information about books that are currently checked out. When the book is returned to the library, the record will be removed from CurrentLoad relation, and will be inserted into History relation with the return-date. A library may have more than one copy of the same book, in which case each copy has its own bookID, but all copies share the same ISBN.

This is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Book
    (bookID INT,
    ISBN INT,
    title varchar (25),
    author  varchar (20),
    publish_year INT,
    category varchar(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (bookID));  

CREATE TABLE Member
    (memberID INT,
    lastname varchar (20),
    firstname varchar (20),
    address varchar(20),
    phone_number INT,   
    limit_ INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID));

CREATE TABLE CurrentLoan
    (memberID INT ,
    bookID INT,
    loan_date DATE,
    due_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID, bookID),
    FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES Book(bookID));


CREATE TABLE History
    (memberID INT,
    bookID INT,
    loan_date DATE,
    return_date DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (memberID, bookID, loan_date),
    FOREIGN KEY (memberID) REFERENCES Member(memberID),
    FOREIGN KEY (bookID) REFERENCES Book(bookID));

INSERT INTO Book VALUES (10, 1113312336, 'The Dog', 'Jack Crow', 1990, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (12, 2221254896, 'Worms', 'Jim Kan', 2013, 'childrens');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (13, 3332546987, 'Crow', 'Jan Flo', 2000, 'fiction'); 
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (14, 4443456215, 'Big Dog', 'Lan Big', 1993, 'children'); 
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (15, 5552314569, 'Green Apple', 'Theo Brown', 1978, 'children');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (16, 6664581631, 'Red Bean', 'Khang Nk', 2017, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (17, 7771452369, 'XML and XQuery Knowledge', 'Author Le', 2017, 'non-fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (18, 8881245525, 'The Dark Room', 'Jack Se', 2017, 'fiction');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (19, 9991123546, 'Lonely Mens', 'Geen Brown', 2014, 'refrence');
INSERT INTO Book VALUES (20, 1122112356, 'XML or XQuery', 'Heart Le', 2002, 'fiction');

INSERT INTO Member VALUES (001, 'Lee', 'Nancy', 'Brownlea Drive', 1254896325, 2);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (002, 'Le', 'Ray', '10th Street', 1234561256, 2);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (003, 'Kan', 'Charlie', '5th Street', 1234567236, 2);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (004, 'Brown', 'Joe', 'Elm Street', 1234567845, 2);
INSERT INTO Member VALUES (005, 'Smith', 'John', '33 East', 1234567890, 2);

INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (005, 10, '13-SEP-17', '14-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (005, 19, '13-JAN-17', '15-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (003, 16, '14-FEB-17', '12-MAR-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (004, 15, '12-OCT-17', '09-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO CurrentLoan VALUES (005, 18, '13-APR-17', '12-MAY-17');

INSERT INTO History VALUES (001, 10, '14-Jan-17', '04-OCT-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (002, 19, '12-Jan-17', '04-NOV-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (003, 13, '14-APR-17', '08-OCT-17');
INSERT INTO History VALUES (005, 20, '14-MAY-17', '04-DEC-17');
```

My query is:

```
SELECT Member.memberID, lastname, firstname 
    FROM Member MINUS(
                    SELECT Member.memberID, lastname, firstname
                    FROM Member, CurrentLoan
                    WHERE Member.memberID = CurrentLoan.memberID
                    UNION
                    SELECT Member.memberID, lastname, firstname
                    FROM Member, History
                    WHERE Member.memberID = History.memberID);
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle?  Why are you using commas in the `FROM` clause.  That is archaic syntax.  Use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: You are subtracting off all five `Member` records in the predicate of your `MINUS` statement.  An empty result set is completely expected.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry, im using Oracle

Comment: What Tim said: You have only five members in your data, with ID from 01 to 05. 01, 02 and 03 appear in the history table. 03, 04 and 05 appear in the current table. So there aren't any members who have never had a loan, in the past OR now. "No rows returned" is the correct answer. That happens often enough in real life too, not just in homework, and I am glad to see homework that teaches you such things early on. It's good homework!

Comment: There are various ways to simplify the query... use UNION ALL instead of UNION (if they didn't teach you why, bring it up to the instructor and ask them to explain the difference, and why UNION ALL is much faster than UNION ). You could also `select id, firstname, lastname from member WHERE id NOT IN (select id from currentloan union all select id from history)` (I didn't use the exact names, you can fix that). This assumes id may not be NULL in currentloan and in history (best to make that explicit by adding constraints to table definitions).

Comment: Why the downvote to this question? It is asked perfectly: *here are statements to create the tables and to insert data; here is my query, the result I get, and what I don't understand.* If anything, this is a model of how questions should be asked.

Comment: @mathguy thank you, i understand now and i will also ask my professor about UNION ALL.

Comment: I would consider ditching the `MINUS` and the joins and write this `WHERE NOT EXISTS (... a current loan for member...) AND NOT EXISTS ( ... a past loan for member ...)`

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - interesting side question... I would instead have the condition like `where not exists (... a current loan UNION ALL a past loan). UNION ALL is a very inexpensive operation, and doing it this way results in a single anti-join. I wonder: with the condition as you wrote it (with AND NOT EXISTS...) will the Optimizer be smart enough to see the same shortcut, or will it instead do two anti-joins, one for each table separately? I don't know the answer, but if this was a meaningful problem where speed was important, it would be good to know.

Comment: @mathguy Agreed-interesting.  I think the `UNION ALL` would be _verrrry_ slightly faster for large, indexed tables.  Same index FFS and table reads, but one hash table probe per member instead of 1-2 my way.  But for a smaller list of members (where nested loop/index access to `CurrentLoan` and `History` would be faster than two `INDEX FULL SCAN` operations), I think the two `NOT EXISTS` would be the optimal plan.  Hopefully Oracle would be smart enough to rewrite the `UNION ALL` in that case.  This is all unverified (though educated?) speculation on my part.  It'd be interesting to test.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to do this:

You can use an anti-join, such as:

```
SELECT m.MEMBERID,
       m.LASTNAME,
       m.FIRSTNAME
  FROM MEMBERS m
  WHERE m.MEMBERID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MEMBERID
                             FROM CURRENTLOAN
                           UNION ALL
                           SELECT DISTINCT MEMBERID
                             FROM HISTORY);
```

Another way (and my preferred method) to do what you want is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.MEMBERID,
                m.LASTNAME,
                m.FIRSTNAME
  FROM MEMBERS m
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT MEMBERID
                     FROM (SELECT MEMBERID
                             FROM CURRENTLOAN
                           UNION ALL
                           SELECT MEMBERID
                             FROM HISTORY)) u
    ON u.MEMBERID = m.MEMBERID
  WHERE u.MEMBERID IS NULL;
```

However, given the data you've shown this query, as well as your original query, should return zero rows. [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/dcacb/2)

Note that if you comment out the current loan to member 004, then "Joe Brown" is returned [SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/68eba/1)

Best of luck.

Comment: It would help to understand *why* you prefer an outer join over an anti-join. One would expect (and some would claim they can prove) that Oracle optimized anti-joins so they work faster than more general left outer joins. (Logically that is obvious - on average, an anti-join needs to check only half of the rows in the "right-side table" for the rows that will be rejected. A standard join will always check all the rows in the right-side table.)

Comment: @mathguy: interesting. I'd be interested if you'd take the time to answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46383003/is-an-anti-join-more-efficient-than-a-left-outer-join). Thanks.

Comment: As to "why do I prefer left outer join with filter to anti-join" - I suppose this may be a carryover from the days I worked with Rdb on a regular basis, where in my 11-year-old recollection anti-joins were generally slow. Old habits die hard. :-) I'll edit and add the anti-join method as well.

Comment: Luckily I have no old habits to forget (I started learning SQL - really only Oracle, the only dialect I know) last year; but from what I've read, until Oracle 8 at least, anti-joins were indeed slow compared to regular joins. But that was a long time ago. Oracle gets some things wrong, but it does get many things right, and they don't stand still.