# SQL join help between two tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables Table a and  Table b.

Table b contains subset of Table a. I would like to get all id IDs of Table a which are not in Table b (id is a common column)  Tried with this SQL, but its not working  select name from table a where name not in

```
select unique name
from table a inner join
     table b
     on a.id = b.id;
```

Appreciate your help

Comment: You'll be much more productive in the future if you get good at googling before asking on SO. This is a common SQL question  https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL+get+all+values+present+in+one+table+but+not+another&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-1-ab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` here. This will retrieve all values from `TableA` and only those that match from `TableB` then in the `WHERE` clause you can test if `TableB` values are NULL, returning only `TableA` values that have no match:

```
 SELECT UNIQUE tableA.id FROM tableA LEFT OUTER JOIN tableB ON a.id = b.id WHERE b.id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use JNevills way by using a `left outer join`.

In oracle you can also use `exists`:

```
with TableA as (
  select 1 as "COL1" from dual
  union all select 2 from dual
  union all select 3 from dual
  union all select 4 from dual
  union all select 5 from dual
), TableB as (
  select 1 as "COL1" from dual
  union all select 2 from dual
  union all select 3 from dual
)
select * 
from TableA
where not exists(select * 
                 from TableB 
                 where TableA.COL1 = TableB.COL1)
```

Comment: This way is better for performance rather than left outer join and is null

Comment: They should be the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff they may be the same, but dont need to. Using the exists syntax makes the optimizer use anti joins which give it the freedom to choose the order of the joins(depending on indices etc). This MAY result in faster execution. See [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46383213/9338645). But I expected it to turn out to be the same as well before :). To verify this you can look up the execution plan where you see an additional `left outer join` in the `left outer join` syntax (OraDB12c).

Comment: @Chrᴉz . . . You are only sort-of right.  I simple Google query suggests that `left join` is faster:  https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9455149500346842527.

Answer (score 0):

Just "select id of a that are not present in table b"

```
select a.id 
from tab_a 
where a.id not in (select b.id from tab_b)
```

Comment: what's the issue?

Comment: this gives a blank result

Comment: code edited, should return you the list of ID in A that do not appear in B

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SQL Minus operator--sometimes implemented as Except (as in SQLite).

```
select id from TableA minus select id from TableB;
select id from TableA except select id from TableB;
```

Comment: `EXCEPT` is actually ANSI/ISO SQL.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this   it works  for me

> SELECT * FROM( SELECT
>   a.id,
>   a.name,
>   COUNT(b.name) AS `count`
>   FROM a
>   LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.name = b.name
>   GROUP BY a.id, a.name) C WHERE C.count=0

Comment: This is way more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: It works surely  ! and why you think It is complicated ?? look http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/972d44/1

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't transcribe it correctly in the SQL fiddle. It does work. As for complexity, you're already left joining the tables so a simple IS NULL filter on the outer table is sufficient (Like JNevill did). The count/subquery is unnecessary.